# How to bind DataGridComboBoxColumn to List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've wanted to create a ComboBoxColumn with specific options for each row

e.g.

List string

```cs
public List<string> Types
        {
            get
            {
                if (PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    return FilterCharacters.BoolList;
                }

                if (PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    return FilterCharacters.TextList;
                }
                if (PropertyType == typeof(int) || PropertyType == typeof(double) ||
                    PropertyType == typeof(float))
                {
                    return FilterCharacters.NumberList;
                }
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }
```

Lists itself

```cs
public static class FilterCharacters
    {
        public static Dictionary<FilterTypes, string> FilterCharactersList => new Dictionary<FilterTypes, string>()
                {
                    {FilterTypes.Equals, "=" },
                    {FilterTypes.NotEquals, "!=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Greater, ">" },
                    {FilterTypes.GreaterOrEqual, ">=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Less, "<" },
                    {FilterTypes.LessOrEqual, "<=" },
                    {FilterTypes.Contains, "contains" },
                    {FilterTypes.NotContains, "does not contain" },
                    {FilterTypes.True, "True" },
                    {FilterTypes.False, "False" }
                };

        public static List<string> NumberList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Greater],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.GreaterOrEqual],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Less],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.LessOrEqual],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Equals],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotEquals]
        };

        public static List<string> TextList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Contains],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotContains],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.Equals],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.NotEquals]
        };

        public static List<string> BoolList => new List<string>()
        {
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.True],
            FilterCharactersList[FilterTypes.False]
        };
    }
```

and xaml

```cs
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="FiltersList1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
...
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}"/>
```

I've tried binding to FiltersList1 **DataContext**, **ItemsSource**, i've also tried specifying the **SelectedItemBinding**, **ComboBoxStyles** but it all ended in either nothing at all (an empty combobox) or an error in the output saying

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
> or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
> BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Types; DataItem=null; target
> element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=15167431); target
> property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

I've ran out of ideas and could not match any found answer on the internet to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use an `ElementStyle` and an `EditingElementStyle` to set the `ItemsSource`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Types}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Types}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did show the items as expected but now i stumbled upon an issue with selecting items. When i change the selection from blank to any element and change cell the selection goes back to the blank one. Do you maybe know how to prevent that?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question has already been answered.